# How have null returned in destructure vs throwing error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a JavaScript destructure like this that works:

```
const {
  data: {currentVal}
} = {
  data: {
    currentVal: "one"
  }
}
```

(working means currentVal is "one")

If data is not defined, my code errors with this:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentVal' of undefined
```

That is, if I change the code to

```
const {
  dataxxx: {currentVal}
} = {
  dataa: {
    currentVal: "one"
  }
}
```

Is there some "?" type syntax I can use so that currentVal ends up undefined instead of throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the default value inside [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const { data: {currentVal} = {}} = {
  dataa: {
    currentVal: "one"
  }
}
console.log(currentVal);
```